# How to convert image pixels to HEX color codes in a txt file?

Tags: image, text, colors, hex

How do I keep only the highlighted part?

[image: Result]

Comment: The hexadecimal number is the concatenation of the 3 color channels. The value for each of the 3 color channels is in range [0, 255] respectively [0x00, 0xff].

Comment: thank you, but do you see that txt file screenshot? 
I want to delete everything except #ABCDEF color codes.
It can be done via a text editor maybe, but I have no clue how to do this..

Comment: So that is not a question about coding?

Comment: this is about text processing

Answer (score 0):

Run it through `awk` to print the 3rd field on every line where the line number is greater than 1:

```
awk 'NR>1{print $3}' YourFile
#574E3E
#2E67FD
#40A254
```